# why importing tensorflow_models interrupt matplotlib in colab?

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, python-import, tensorflow-model-garden

Running

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()
```

plots the plot with no problem, but

```py
import tensorflow_models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()
```

doesn't plot anythig. I use colab notebook. Why is this happan?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't install the requires packages, first you have to install the package for imported modules by code below

```
!pip install tf-models-official
```

and next you must add a line for matplotlib in colab, see below

```
%matplotlib inline # line to add!
import tensorflow_models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()
```